# ActionScript creating custom component to hold two other spark components

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, custom-component, flex-spark

I'm fairly new to ActionScript/Flex so I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible.

Basically I have the following block repeating several times in my code:

```
<s:TextInput .. \>
<s:BitmapImage .. \>
```

What I'm trying to do is create an ActionScript custom component so I can replace the above block everywhere in my code with:

```
<MyBlock\>
```

My best guess is I have to do this by extending spark.application?

What I have so far:

```
package MyPackage
{
   import spark.components.Application;

   public class MyBlock extends Application
   {
     ..
   }
..
}
```

I am completely at a loss as to how to combine two existing components into a new custom one, if it is even possible.

How exactly should I proceed next? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so much easier than that: for this use case you should simply extend `Group`. And to make things easier, write your composed component in MXML.

Create a new file `MyBlock.mxml` (for instance in `com/mydomain/components`) and add the following code:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:TextInput .. />
    <s:BitmapImage .. />
</s:Group>
```

Now simply use this component:

```
<c:MyBlock />
```

where the `c` namespace is defined as `xmlns:c="com.mydomain.components.*"` at the root node of your document using this class. For example:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:c="com.mydomain.components.*">
    <c:MyBlock />
</s:Application>
```

---

Now suppose you want to have a different text in each block, you'll have to expose a property. To do this, lets add a `label` property to `MyBlock`:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:String id="label" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

To make the `TextInput` show what's in that variable whenever it changes, we use binding like so:

```
<s:TextInput text="{label}" />
```

The final component would look something like this:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String id="label" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextInput text="{label}" .. />
    <s:BitmapImage .. />
</s:Group>
```

Now you can create multiple `MyBlock` instances with different texts:

```
<c:MyBlock label="hello" />
<c:MyBlock label="world" />
```

---

Note that if your regular use of MyBlock is more in a list-like fashion, you may want to consider using a `List` component with a custom ItemRenderer, rather then using `MyBlock` over and over again.

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually what I had in mind was a boolean property, so that when the property is set to true MyBlock would show one image and a different one for false. I think I can get working on that the same way, thanks!